# Django-Celery - Resubmit tasks from admin page?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm currently working on a project using Django 1.3 with the Django-Celery app.  It's pretty awesome, by the way, I suggest anyone who's not familiar with celery check it out.

I have a specific question around the admin page functionality:

We're using celery tasks to make RESTful API calls to third party partners.  These calls are actually kicked off by a user action, so you could see how a celery task would be extremely useful in this case.

We have a user story around how an admin should be able to re-send a callback if it fails for some reason.  Now, if the callback fails with a standard HTTP response failure, we are using the celery retry mechanism to automatically resend them at various intervals.  However, these callbacks could be to one of any thousands of partners (yea, theres a lot), and not all of them will use a standard HTTP Response code as their failure response.

Long story short, I haven't been able to find anything online that states that one can re-send a celery task through the admin interface.  I was hoping that someone could shed some light on this.  It seems like a pretty obvious piece of functionality to have, and if there is no such functionality I'm sure there's a good reason for it.  I'd love it if there isn't a way to do it, if someone could explain the reason.  Just curious to learn more about the internal workings of celery.

Thanks everyone! Sorry for my wordiness, sometimes I tend to ramble.

Comment: BTW - on a side note, if there isn't a way to re-send tasks, I'll implement one myself in the admin.  In order to do so, I need to store the args pickled in the DB.  Does anyone know if there is a way in python to get a tuple of the passed-in arguments besides manually creating it?  This is just something I'm curious about.  Sorry, I know I'm breaking the rule of two questions in one post... but technically it's a comment so I thought I'd be safe, hehe.

Comment: For the arg question, create a function as 'def myFunc(*args)' any passed arguments will be in the tuple 'args'.

Comment: I see, so if I add *args to the method then all passed in arguments will be in the args list.  I was familiar with this feature, but unaware that it worked in that way, with already defined non-keyword arguments.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: 2021 Update - I've implemented a Django Admin Action for retrying Celery Tasks. Check [here](https://gist.github.com/sameerkumar18/e792fa6026e063eaef695b3c271959e6) for the gist. And [here](https://medium.com/@sameer_kumar/celery-django-admin-action-to-manually-retry-tasks-90b8013b0b8f) are a few words about it. 
Appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try two approaches,

**1: Small hack in model:**

You can use a boolean field and name it something like celery_retry and in models save method do something like this.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.celery_retry and self.user.is_superuser():
          celery_task.apply_async()
    self.celery_retry = False
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is just an idea, you can determine your own how and when to submit celery task back.

**2:Extend admin template:**

You can extend the admin template and put in a hyperlink to a view which resubmits the task.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I ended up doing #1.  I was looking for more of a built-in method.  It seemed to be something that would be included from looking at the current featureset.  Either way, this is the correct response, so I'm giving you a nice green check mark.